# An Idea for an app but I don't know if kivy capable of that

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, android-gps

I have some problem and I'll list them here:

1. Emulator for iPhone and Android, how can I build an app for iPhone/Android using kivy but I have not emulators open source to see how my app works and performs? Do I have to always download the app to my phone to check it?
2. How do I show a map using kivy and show my current location constantly (while moving) just like google maps and waze? How do I use the phone location service without a phone emulator how's that work?

Does Kivy capable of that?

```
from kivy.app import App
from plyer import gps


class MainApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        gps.configure(on_location=self.on_gps_location)
        gps.start()

    def on_gps_location(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)


MainApp().run()
```

This is a code I found on youtube but it raises an exception

```
Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError
exception: no description
  File "C:\Users\talns\Application\main.py", line 7, in on_start
    gps.configure(on_location=self.on_gps_location)
  File "C:\Users\talns\Application\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    MainApp().run()
```